# Check if an entry exists in AutoCorrect.Entries

Tags: vba, ms-word, autocorrect

Is there an efficient way of looking up a name in the AutoCorrect.Entries for MS Word to check if it exists (before I add a new entry with that name; I have the code that adds the entry and it works but it REPLACES the entry if it exists)

```
Sub AutoCorrection()
'
' AutoCorrect Macro
'
'
Dim selected As Variant
Dim name As Variant

'selected text gets stored as the selected
selected = Selection

'Checking if selected text is less than 2 characters.
If Len(selected) < 2 Then
    MsgBox "Select text for autocorrect", vbOKOnly, "Nothing Selected"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Displaying the selected text and getting input for the name
name = InputBox(selected, "Name for this autocorrect?")

'*** In here, I want to check if this name exists in the entries before adding a new entry ***

AutoCorrect.Entries.AddRichText name:=name, Range:=Selection.Range
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.autocorrect.entries shows how to loop over the entries.

Answer (score 0):

### The following should work.

```
Private Function AutoCorrectEntryExist(strName As String) As Boolean
    ' Charles Kenyon 2022-06-14 Reports True if an AutoCorrect Entry uses the name given in strName
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619065/check-if-an-entry-exists-in-autocorrect-entries/72625298#72625298
    '
    Dim oEntry As Word.AutoCorrectEntry
    For Each oEntry In AutoCorrect.Entries
        If oEntry.Name = strName Then
            MsgBox prompt:=strName & " is already in use, Choose a different name.", title:="In Use!", buttons:=vbCritical
            AutoCorrectEntryExist = True
            GoTo EntryFound
        End If
    Next oEntry
    AutoCorrectEntryExist = False
EntryFound:
    Set oEntry = Nothing
End Function
```

You would call it from your procedure with the name you want to use. It will report False if the name is not in use and True if it is.

```
If AutoCorrectEntryExist(name) = True Then
   ' code here to use if already used
End If
```

You could skip the msgBox in the Function.
This is NOT going to be fast if you have many entries.

*btw, "name" is a terrible name for your variable, IMO.*

Comment: Thank you so much!!! and yes you're right I changed the "name" name :| oh and I put a REDO: before the name input and then where you commented (in the function call), I put "goto REDO" so it's a neat loop until new name is added lol